# Cannot assign requested address for bind the socket

Tags: c, windows, sockets, tcp

I checked my code but I don't know why the program can't bind the socket.
I tried many ip and ports(even 127.0.0.1) but it still don't works...
Here is the code I'm using :

```
//error message
void error (const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

int main ()
{
    int sock, cli_sock, portno;
    char buffer[1024];
    char response[18432];

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    socklen_t cli_len;

    //creating socket
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sock < 0)
        error("Error opening socket");

    bzero ((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

    //giving port number
    portno = 50005;

    //giving ip address
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    //bind socket
    if(bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) != 0)
        error("Binding failed.");

    //listen
    listen(sock, 5);

    cli_len = sizeof(cli_addr);

    //accept
    cli_sock = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &cli_len);
    if(cli_sock != 0)
        error("Error on accepting");
}
```

(This is just the socket part of the server code and just for more info, my client version is for Windows and my server version is for Linux)

This is my output when I run the program :

`Binding failed.: Cannot assign requested address`

Comment: This error is about the address, not the port. It is not possible that 127.0.0.1 produced this error, but you should be using INADDR_ANY unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: But `cli_sock != 0` only indicates an error if `cli_sock == -1`. Otherwise it is a *success*.

Comment: Does the real code also miss any `#include`s?

Comment: @user207421 Yes I want this program to communicate with another system(out of my network) so I need to use a not local ip in the end. But the problem is as you said it produce this error even with local ip!!!

Comment: @alk I'm almost sure that I didn't miss any header files because it compiles with no errors. But not work when running.

Comment: @MoeinMhzg Not only do you *not* need to use a non-local IP address to bind to, you *can't*, as the error message is plainly telling you. What happened when you tried INADDR_ANY as I suggested? And please don't try to convince me that you can't bind to 127.0.0.1 and that you get this error message instead.

Comment: Does it compile without warnings, when compiled with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`?

Comment: OT: Do not use `bzero()` any more it is not part of C nor of POSIX any more. Use `memset()` instead.

Comment: @user207421 I tried INADDR_ANY, it ran with no error but it don't connect.
I mean it shows nothing. no errors but just empty screen. it don't communicate.

Comment: @alk yes it compile with no error with ` -Wall -Wextra -pedantic` and I also replace `bzero`s with `memset`

Comment: the real problem is I don't get any outputs neither from server nor from client. I watched many videos on YouTube and write the exact code they used, but it worked for them but not for me. I don't know what should I do...
I tried many codes and many ways but it just don't give me any output from anywhere...
I can write my both client and server code if you want.

Comment: btw I am using VM Linux and Windows 10 to test my program. do I need set port forwarding for my VM(even tho I tried port forwarding too but as always no outputs). I just wanna make sure generally should I set port forwarding or not?

Comment: also I really get confused because every body write socket codes in a different way with different functions. for example :
https://aticleworld.com/socket-programming-in-c-using-tcpip/
in this code there is no acpt or listen function.

https://youtu.be/DboEGcU6rLI
and in this video he use almost completely different functions ...

Comment: @user207421 I replaced `bind` with `connect`, and `127.0.0.1` for ip address and this is my output : `Connection refused` !!!

Comment: Replacing `bind()` with `connect()` makes no sense. Either you're a server or a client. Make up your mind. You must also have removed the `listen()` call or you would have got a different error. If you got past the `bind()` call when you ued INADDR_ANY that is progress: now you have a different problem. Is the client trying to connect to this server? *Is* there a client?

Answer (score -1):

For TCP the setup for client and server were:

Server:

- socket (create listening socket)
- bind (listening socker to local address:port)
- listen (make listening socket actually listen)

(accept loop header)

- accept (have listening socket wait for incoming connections; returns accepted socket on succesful connection)
- read/write (from/to accepted socket!)
- shutdown (accepted socket; optional)
- close (accepted socket)

(loop footer)

- shutdown (listening socket; optional)
- close (listening socket)

Client:

- socket
- bind (to local address:port, optional and uncommon)
- connect (to remote address:port, those the server was bound to)
- read/write
- shutdown (optional)
- close

Comment: First of all really thank you for your time sir.
Do I need `bind` for Client too?
btw I tried both (`bind` then `connect` and just `connect`), and I put a if for checking the problem, and I get error message for `bind` or `connect`(in first case that I used `bind` and then `connect` I got error from `bind` and in other case that I didn't use `bind`, I got error from `connect`

Comment: Here is my Client code :

```int main()
{
 int sock, portno;
 struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
//creating socket
 sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

 memset((char *) &serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));

 portno = 50005;

 serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
 serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
 serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

 bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

 connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
}```

Comment: of curse the code have continuation. I just write the socket part(before read and write functions) .